# Ingresar un contador de lectura a variable

Tags: windows, shell, consola, powershell, cmd

Hola que tal muy buenas tardes, lo que que pretendo quiero hacer es contar x veces una palabra definida en un texto y después de esto meterla en una variable la cual será impresa en un cuadro emergente. El poco código que tengo es esto:

```
@echo off
:bucle
find /c "Perl" < texto.txt
pause > nul
goto bucle
```

teniendo en cuenta que nuestro texto a leer es el siguiente:

> Perl es un lenguaje de programación diseñado por Larry Wall creado en
>   1987.  Perl toma características del C, del lenguaje interpretado shell (sh), AWK,  sed, Lisp y, en un grado inferior, de muchos otros
>   lenguajes de programación.
>
> Estructuralmente, Perl está basado en un estilo de bloques como los
>   del C  o AWK, y fue ampliamente adoptado por su destreza en el
>   procesado de texto  y no tener ninguna de las limitaciones de los
>   otros lenguajes de script.

ya eh intentado con el comando

```
set InserteVariable= find
```

pero creo que voy por mal camino. 
De antemano agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Échale un ojo a esta [solución **en inglés**](http://superuser.com/questions/939838/how-do-i-count-all-occurrences-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-batch-fi/939864#939864)

Comment: Muchas gracias.. me ha servido bastante :)